# How to fix `sh: ___: command not found` for NPM Modules

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm relatively new to Node development and I'm trying out various modules, frameworks, etc.. I'm on macOS Catalina. I've changed my NPM root and $PATH while trying to get things to work, and I think I broke something, though I'm not exactly sure what. My issue is very specifically with NPM, which is having a persistent problem running installed modules both locally and globally. When I try to install a dev tool like Nodemon or a framework like Electron, I get error codes like:

```
sh: electron: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've consulted a lot of resources and a lot of questions on this site, but I'm not experienced enough to accurately troubleshoot this issue and identify what's going on. While I'm shooting in the dark, I may be fixing one thing and breaking another, so I'm coming here to see if I can get a comprehensive answer.

I'll add that I've found a few workarounds, if this makes the issue clearer at all. I can get some modules (in this example Nodemon) to run by adding this "dev" script to the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node ./node_modules/.bin/nodemon server.js"
  }
```

So I can access local project modules by specifying the path of the Module, but I can't just say "nodemon server.js", either in the dev script or from the command line, where it should have been installed globally. If I look in the specified `npm -g root` folder, the packages I'm trying to run are definitely in there, so it's not an installation issue.

Any guidance y'all have is greatly appreciated, as I don't know what to make of all this.

Comment: Just checking in if anyone knows about this.

Comment: still checking.

Answer (score 0):

For those having trouble with this add this to your: `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=./node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue may arise from several factors :

#### NPM installation

Certain Node.js installers, especially those that use a package manager like Homebrew (`brew`), or Node Version Manager (`nvm`), manage `PATH` updates differently.
Installers typically attempt to modify the profile script (e.g., `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`) to ensure the global npm directory is in the `PATH`.
If Node.js was installed in a way that doesn't automatically update the `PATH`, or if the installation scripts were unable to modify the shell profile correctly, you might need to manually add the global npm modules directory to your `PATH`.

So, to use globally installed modules, if you get the `command not found` error, follow these steps :

- Get npm global installation directory with `npm get prefix`

  ```
  $> npm get prefix
  /usr/local
  ```
- If you don't already have it in your `PATH` (with the `/bin` folder appended), manually add it to your shell's profile script (e.g., `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`) :
  `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`
- Start a new shell and try to run a globally installed npm command

#### Local project node modules

You can't run directly a module's command from within a project, you need to add a script in your `package.json` like you did :

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon server.js"
}
```

Why it does not work for you unless you put `node ./node_modules/.bin/nodemon` instead is unclear without more specifics on your system context, but that *should* work like this.
You may check execution permissions on the files in your project `node_modules/.bin` folder maybe.
Sometimes completely deleting the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` to make a fresh install may help too.

#### Use `npx`

As a last resort, you can leverage the command `npx` instead that will automatically run a command from a local or remote npm package and install it globally if it does not exist yet on your system.

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "npx nodemon server.js"
}
```

```bash
$> npx nodemon server.js
```

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx for more details.

---

## Note on how to install npm modules

There are 2 installation style, local and global, on npm.
It is highly recommended to not mix both on the same environment, at least for a given module.

### Global installation

e.g. `npm install -g <module name>`

The executable(s) provided by the module you have installed will be added into a global directory that *should* already be included in your environment `PATH` when you installed npm.
You can then use this command everywhere, but you cannot use different versions for each project in your environment. You can isolate this behavior with `nvm`, or in a container.

### Local project installation

e.g. `npm install --save <module name>`

The executable(s) will be installed into the project `node_modules` directory and saved (`--save` or `--save-*` flags) in the `package.json`.
Your projects will use the local module version and you can easily manage it with `package.json`.
`PATH` environment variable does not include this local folder. You have to use either:

- directly calling the local executable with `./node_modules/.bin/<command>`, as you did in your workaround, or `$(npm root)/.bin/<command>`.
- better use the `npm run-script` command by defining a specific script in the local `package.json` file, this way  `npm` will automatically find the executable in `./node_modules/.bin`.

  ```json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx nodemon server.js"
  }
  ```

  See also: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script