# How do I solve npm run build command not found error?

Tags: visual-studio, npm

I have this in my script

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack",
    "compile": "tsc -p tsconfig.sequences.json",
    "build": "npm-run-all -p compile start",
```

But getting this error message

```
sh: npm-run-all: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! workshop4@1.0.0 build: `npm-run-all -p compile start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the workshop4@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have version 6.13.4 npm and node 12.14

Answer (score 1):

You probably did not installed `npm-run-all` properly.

I would suggest to ensure you installed it locally with:

```
npm i -s npm-run-all
```

You then should be able to use it in npm-scripts.

See this answer for more context on how to use commands from npm modules depending on the way you installed them:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65773947/3612177